# VBA script that will find a cell with specific name

Tags: vba, return-value, spreadsheet

I have found many posts similar to what I am trying to accomplish, but nothing that I have been able to modify and make work.
I have two spreadsheets and I need a VBA script that will find a cell with specific name let's say "Light bulb" in spreadsheet2 and then copy the adjacent values (below it) to cell A2 on spreadsheet1.
Would appreciate any help

Comment: When you say "name" do you mean a named range referring to a single cell, or do you mean the text "Light Bulb" is actually in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually looking for text in some cell (like a heading), and you want to copy the heading and the values below that heading, you would do something like this:

```
Sub LightBulb()
Dim rng As Range
Dim fnd As String
fnd = "Light Bulb"

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(fnd)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Range(Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column), _
      Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
      Cells(1, 1).Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it works great thanks a lot, the only thing that it also copies table name with values. How do  i change it so it will copy only values without table name. Tahnks

Comment: Oh, you're using tables! That actually makes this a lot easier (but different.) It's late here, so please come back tomorrow and I will add how to do it based on a table.